# Unable to run the simplest Spark Streaming application ever

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

With the following ultra simple streaming app:

```
object Streaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

    val lines = streamingContext.socketTextStream("localhost", 8888)
    lines.print()

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Running `sbt run` and sending a text to this host, I'm getting this amazing error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1331)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:735)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:734)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1358)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1331)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:735)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:734)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
[error]     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
15:25:30.859 [spark-listener-group-executorManagement] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue - Stopping listener queue executorManagement.
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2050)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2084)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:94)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
15:25:30.859 [spark-listener-group-shared] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue - Stopping listener queue shared.
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2050)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2084)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:94)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
15:25:30.860 [spark-listener-group-appStatus] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue - Stopping listener queue appStatus.
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2050)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2084)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:94)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
15:25:30.860 [org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem - exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3063)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
15:25:30.862 [Spark Context Cleaner] ERROR org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:73)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]     at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:124)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1185)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1180)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:366)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:289)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Here is the full project: https://github.com/joan38/spark-issue

Comment: It successfully runs with exact IP intead of `localhost` in my case, so I assume it's more of environment issue rather than Spark's one.

Comment: Are you speaking about the `socketTextStream`? Because I get the same with `textFileStream` :/

Comment: I cloned your repo and just ran it, while setting up `ncat` to stream data from /dev/random on 127.0.0.1:888. Then your spark app had read and print data from socket.

Comment: what java version are you using? with `java --version`

Comment: I'm using `java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17` Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run it in a Docker container so I guess it's environmental as gemelen commented.